# how to deal with hyphen (-) before node xml xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

hi guys so i have a problem with an xml, it has - before node and i dont know how to deal with this properly with xpath, so the xml would look like this

```
<xml>
 <item>
 -<description>
  -<type>
   </type>
  </description>
 </item>
</xml>
```

so how can i navigate down to say type in xpath just before anyone wastes any time giving out the wrong answer i have tried the normal method of $xml->item->description->type this does not work in this case i dont know as its not an illegal character in the name how to deal with the - before th nodes

Comment: @JohnKugelman you're right; deleting my half-cocked comment... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a waste of time to point out that `/xml/item/description/type` *does* in fact work (in XPath 1.0 and 2.0 in XmlSpy).

That said, I think that perhaps you don't really want those '-' characters in your xml. Perhaps a better question would be "How do I strip extraneous '-' characters from xml?"

*Edit:*

Here's some PHP adapted from the [SimpleXMLElement documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to show you that I'm not lying:

```
<?php
    $string =
    "<xml>
     <item>
     -<description>
      -<type>
          Hello World!
       </type>
      </description>
     </item>
    </xml>";

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

    $path = '/xml/item/description/type';

    $result = $xml->xpath('/xml/item/description/type');

    while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
        echo '$path: ',$node,"\n";
    }
?>
```

Outputs:

```
/xml/item/description/type:
    Hello World!
```

If you want any further help, please provide a short example that reproduces the issue.

(Apologies if my PHP is bad, I'm a bit rusty)

Comment: To which I think the answer *might* be, don't copy and paste it from internet explorer's annoying XML viewer.

Comment: i tried to use something like //type to get every instance regardless of position but because the xml has bad characters it doesnt work nor does trying to set it as description/type i simply need to know how to get past them if im using xpath in php like an array

Comment: also im not trying to process that above something completely different apart from the problem it is not a static file rather and xml output of someones DB

Comment: i don't use IE its pathetic this was actually a saved xml anyhow the the - characters are in the feed regardless of where i save the file if i print the file as a string in php its there in the string and im talking about php xpath not xsl

Comment: Ok, why don't you post some real-world xml [somewhere](http://pastebin.com/)? At the moment all you have is a woolly assertion that XPaths don't work, which is not much for us to go on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15632/discussion-between-richardtowers-and-dominic-noble)